# Access `from` component when route params change in Vue

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vue-router

I have a simple route `Question`, it looks like `question/:id`. Also I have a `CurrentQuestion` component, which has dynamic component inside based on the value.

What I want to achieve is following:

1. Change question from 1 to 2 (watch `$route` triggers)
2. Before `CurrentQuestion` changes - access `from` component.

Tried `beforeRouteUpdate` - it doesn't even triggers.
Watching `$route` and accessing `this` results in the next question already. Any ideas to handle this?

Comment: Can you share code you have tried so far?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was because of me trying to trigger `beforeRouteUpdate` into nested component. This should be operated within main component, fixed by moving to parent of dynamic component.